# UIBackgroundModes, Logging out on temporary (or permanent) exit

Tags: iphone, ios, background, logout

I'm maintaining an iPhone app for a client. The app does not run in the background (Applications does not run in the background = YES in settings plist). However, when the user is temporarily interrupted (for example by a phone call) or when the app exists, the users needs to be logged out. I currently do this in applicationWillResignActive:. I first thought about using the beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler but then noticed that the return value was always "UIBackgroundTaskInvalid". I assume this is because I can't run in the background. The question then is, how should I handle the logout? Should I make the logout synchronous and hope that it finishes on time (I guess within 10 seconds?).

At first I wasn't aware of this beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler not returning a valid background task identifier and the apps were logging out fine. Except one of the users kept having crashes with " has active assertions beyond permitted time” (on iPad 1).

Anyone else dealt with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your app doesn't Background, then you would need to do your logging out in the the provided `-applicationWillTerminate:` method. As that's what will be called when theres an interruption or the app is closed.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
/*
 Called when the application is about to terminate.
 Save data if appropriate.
 */

}
```

Comment: applicationWillTerminate: does not get called for interruptions (like phone calls) even when the app does not support background. applicationWillResignActive: does get called however, and this is exactly where I am logging the user out now. It works fine except for the iPad 1 occasional crash that has me worried about what I'm doing. The basic question is, when you are not running background modes, how can you ensure the user gets logged out? How much time does an app get to finish the task, and must this task be on the UI thread?